# error: class,interface, or enum expected?

Tags: java, android

Então galera tava aqui tentando fazer um exercicio de jogo da velha no android studio e não consigo achar onde está o erro, gostaria de alguma ajuda.

```
 package com.example.francisco.jogodavelha;

 import android.app.AlertDialog; import
 android.content.DialogInterface; import
 android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.Menu; import android.view.MenuItem; import
 android.view.View; import android.widget.Button; import
 android.widget.Toast;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     public final int BOLA = 1;
     public final int CRUZ = 2;

     int turno;
     int rodada;

     public void VerificarFim() {
         int vencedor = 0;
         if (bot[0].getValor() == bot[1].getValor() && bot[1].getValor() == bot[2].getValor()) {
             vencedor = bot[0].getValor();
         } else if (bot[3].getValor() == bot[4].getValor() && bot[4].getValor() == bot[5].getValor()) {
             vencedor = bot[3].getValor();
         } else if (bot[6].getValor() == bot[7].getValor() && bot[7].getValor() == bot[8].getValor()) {
             vencedor = bot[6].getValor();
         } else if (bot[0].getValor() == bot[3].getValor() && bot[3].getValor() == bot[6].getValor()) {
             vencedor = bot[0].getValor();
         } else if (bot[1].getValor() == bot[4].getValor() && bot[4].getValor() == bot[7].getValor()) {
             vencedor = bot[1].getValor();
         } else if (bot[2].getValor() == bot[4].getValor() && bot[4].getValor() == bot[8].getValor()) {
             vencedor = bot[2].getValor();
         } else if (bot[0].getValor() == bot[4].getValor() && bot[1].getValor() == bot[2].getValor()) {
             vencedor = bot[0].getValor();
         } else if (bot[2].getValor() == bot[4].getValor() && bot[4].getValor() == bot[6].getValor()) {
             vencedor = bot[2].getValor();
         }
         if (rodada > 9 && vencedor == 0) {
             vencedor = -1;
         }
         if (vencedor != 0) {
             String textovit = "";
             if (vencedor == BOLA) {
                 textovit = "Bola Venceu, ";
             } else if (vencedor == CRUZ) {
                 textovit = "Cruz Venceu, ";
             } else {
                 textovit = "Houve um empate";
             }
             textovit += "Deseja jogar novamente?";
         }

         AlertDialog.Buider buider = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

         builder.setTitle("Fim de jogo");
         buider.setMessage(textovit);
         builder.setCancelable(false);

         buider.setPositiveButton("Jogar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                 for (int i = 0; i<9; i++){
                     bot[i].getBot().setEnabled(true);
                     bot[i].getBot().setText("");
                     bot[i].setValor(0);
                 }
             }
         });
         builder.setNegativeButton("sair", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
             public void onClick (DialogInterface dialog,int which){
                 finish();
             }
         });

         AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
         alert.show();
     } 
}

 class Botao {
     private Button bot;
     private int valor;

     public void setValor(int valor) {
         this.valor = valor;
     }

     public Button getBot() {
         return this.bot;
     }

     public int getValor() {
         return this.valor;
     }

     public Botao(Button bot) {
         this.bot = bot;
         this.valor = 0;
         this.bot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 getBot().setEnabled(false);
                 setValor(turno);
                 if (turno == BOLA) {
                     getBot().setText("0");
                     turno = CRUZ;
                 } else {
                     getBot().setText("X");
                     turno = BOLA;
                 }
                 rodada++;
                 VerificarFim();
             }

         });
     }
 }
     Botao[] bot;

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         turno = BOLA;
         rodada = 1;
         bot = new Botao[9];
         bot[0] = new Botao ( (Button) findViewById(R.id.bot1));
         bot[1] = new Botao ( (Button) findViewById(R.id.bot2));
         bot[2] = new Botao ( (Button) findViewById(R.id.bot3));
         bot[3] = new Botao ( (Button) findViewById(R.id.bot4));
         bot[4] = new Botao ( (Button) findViewById(R.id.bot5));
         bot[5] = new Botao ( (Button) findViewById(R.id.bot6));
         bot[6] = new Botao ( (Button) findViewById(R.id.bot7));
         bot[7] = new Botao ( (Button) findViewById(R.id.bot8));
         bot[8] = new Botao ( (Button) findViewById(R.id.bot9));

     }
     @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
         // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
         return true;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Você poderia adicionar o stacktrace completo? Ficará mais fácil lhe ajudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se sua `MainActivity` está exatamente do jeito que postou na sua questão, seu problema está na parte final da sua classe.

Essa parte do código (abaixo), provavelmente pertence a sua `MainActivity` e neste momento está em lugar algum, pois tem um fechamento de chave (`}`) errado em algum lugar.

```
 Botao[] bot;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     turno = BOLA;
     rodada = 1;
     bot = new Botao[9];
     bot[0] = new Botao ( (Button) findViewById(R.id.bot1));
     bot[1] = new Botao ( (Button) findViewById(R.id.bot2));
     bot[2] = new Botao ( (Button) findViewById(R.id.bot3));
     bot[3] = new Botao ( (Button) findViewById(R.id.bot4));
     bot[4] = new Botao ( (Button) findViewById(R.id.bot5));
     bot[5] = new Botao ( (Button) findViewById(R.id.bot6));
     bot[6] = new Botao ( (Button) findViewById(R.id.bot7));
     bot[7] = new Botao ( (Button) findViewById(R.id.bot8));
     bot[8] = new Botao ( (Button) findViewById(R.id.bot9));

 }
 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
     return true;
 }
}
```

Se sua classe `Botao` for uma `innerClass`, você deve remover o fecha chaves `}` logo antes da linha `class Botao {` se for uma classe externa a sua `MainActivity` você deve pegar o código acima e colocar antes do fecha chaves antes da classe `Botao`